# Where I should use the tag <menu>, and where the tag <nav>?

Tags: html, menu, tags, nav

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<nav> or <menu> (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969801/nav-or-menu-html5)

HTML have two semantic tags for create a menu in a page. Where I should use the tag `<menu>`, and where the tag `<nav>`. What is the difference in these tags?
P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<nav>` Should be used for site/page navigation - it implies that clicking links in a nav element will take the browser to different content. It is quite widely supported and the latest version of most browsers will handle it natively.

`<menu>` Is for UI features that don't effect actual navigation - for example, if you had a rich text editor, any buttons you have for text formatting could go in a menu element. As far as I know menu isn't supported by anybody yet.