# What html5 tag should be used for filtering search results

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

If I have an area of a page with different options for filtering the search results (unordered lists with links, checkboxes, selects, etc.). What html5 tag should be used to wrap that filters? A "section" tag, a "nav" tag or something else?

```
<div id="search-filters"> <!-- This should be a div, a nav, a section? -->
    <h3>Price</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>less than 100</li>
        <li>100 - 200</li>
        <li>more than 200</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Brand</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Brand A</li>
        <li>Brand B</li>
        <li>Brand C</li>
    </ul>

    ...
</div>
<section id="search_results">
    ...
</section>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element):

> The `header` element represents a group of introductory or **navigational aids**.

Note that the `header` needs to be *in* the sectioning element (in your case, `section`) of the search results:

```
<section id="search_results">

  <h1>Search results</h1>

  <header id="search-filters">
    <!-- your filters -->
  </header>

  <article>
    <!-- search result 1 -->
  </article>

  <article>
    <!-- search result 2 -->
  </article>

</section>
```

You could include the `h1` in the `header` too, if you like. If you then need a styling hook for the filters, you could use a wrapper `div`.

If your filters are rather complex, e.g. if you offer many filters, probably with subheadings, you could use a `section` element inside of the `header`:

```
<section id="search_results">

  <h1>Search results</h1>

  <header id="search-filters">
    <section>
      <h2>Filter the results</h2>
      <!-- your filters -->
    </section>
  </header>

  <article>
    <!-- search result 1 -->
  </article>

  <article>
    <!-- search result 2 -->
  </article>

</section>
```

Comment: I like this proposal for search filters, but what do you means with "Search result 1" and "search results 2"? each item returned in search results? I've never though in those Iike articles...

Comment: @hernan-scribe: Yes, in general each item (= search result) can be an own `article`. However, it depends on the kind of results whether you should use `article` or not. -- But this is off-topic here, using `header` for the filters works for any markup you choose for the search result items.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
<nav role="search">
...
</nav>
```

I know it's not perfect, since..

1. `nav` doesn't really state in the standard that it should be used, but it's clearly something that leads you to different pages (which is). There isn't anything better, though you could also use `menu`, since it can also be seen as a command ([1](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-command-element),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969801/nav-or-menu-html5)).
2. And it's not really a "search" role, since you said it's filtering what is already searched, but I think it's the closest to it.

Answer (score -5):

I would use something like this in the html:

```
<form method="get">
    Search By Client Name: <input type="search" name="searchText" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

And in the controller, something like this:

```
// GET: /Clients/

MyContextDB db = new MyContextDB();

public ActionResult Index(string searchText = null)
{
    var model =
    db.ClientProfiles
        .OrderBy(r => r.ClientName)
        .Where(r => searchText == null || r.ClientName.StartsWith(searchText))
        .Take(2)
        .Select(r => new ClientListViewModel {
            ClientId = r.ClientId,
            ClientName = r.ClientName,
            ....
        });

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: sorry but I'm asking about an HTML 5 tag, I think this answer is for another question...

Comment: @hernan-scribe - Your wuestion's not clear. Consider providing some markup as an example of what you want wrapping.

Comment: @Alohci could be the English is not my language. but I asked about an HTML5 Tag (section, nav, article...) to use for the section where the filter options are. If you have filters options on a page like age, price, size, weight, brand, etc., that options should be inside a "section", a "nav" according to HTML5 specs, or just use DIVs ?

Comment: @hernan-scribe - Depending on the details, I'd go for either fieldset or div, neither of which are new in HTML5. Sectioning content wouldn't normally be appropriate, but using a section element can't be ruled out in all circumstances.There's nothing else newly appropriate in HTML5 unless the filters were only for advanced use, in which case details/summary would be a possibility.

Comment: @hernan-scribe - based on your example, either section or div would be fine.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you, but now I don't know how to mark your answer as usefull and acepted... :)

Comment: Sorry if my post was confusing. What I was illustrating was an instance of a semantic search tag and figured I'd give you the round trip. From what I understand about Semantic Tags, basically they are used to layout a page in a way that makes human sense. Typically using Articles for containing Sections and a Sidebar for asides. As well as the self-explanatory Header and Footer Tags. The Article tag is a standalone where a Section tag would have an implicit dependency to an Article. Hopefully it's clearer.