# How to detect mouse is over a child element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu-submenu-subsubmenu construction in HTML like this:

```
<menu>
    <li><a href="...">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><ul>
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 2</a></li>
            <li><ul>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="...">Subitem 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="...">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="...">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Item 4</a></li>
```

...using whit this css formating:

```
menu {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
/* hide subitems */
menu li ul,
menu li ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
/* set up positions */
menu li ul {
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
menu li ul li ul {
    left: 400px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

I use this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    /* hide all submenu */
    $('menu').find('ul').hide();
    /* show submenu on mouseenter */
    $('menu li a').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').hide();
    });
});
```

How can I detect mouse is leaving the element to their child? Or how can I get the child element to stay if it's necessary?

Comment: won't you need the same thing like `menu > ul > li > ul`

Comment: I think not the tag names is the essence. Change it to `<nav>` if this is problem. ;)

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/xSN2S/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `li` should be within a `ul`.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, but not because of what @putvande or @Mr. Alien have said. [To fix it, you need to add a `[type="toolbar"]` attribute to your `<menu>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-menu-element). Alternatively, if your menu is meant to contain navigational links, rather than interactive javascript driven controls for a web application, [you should be using the `<nav>` element with a `<ul>` or `<ol>` child element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4971434/497418).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to be like this:

```
$(function() {
/* hide all submenu */
$('menu').find('ul').hide();
/* show submenu on mouseenter */ 

// here, just select the direct child
$('menu').find('li > a, li > ul').mouseenter(function() {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show().data('showing-time', time);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var leaveTime = new Date().getTime();
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var $ul = $this.parent().find('ul');
        var beginTime = $ul.data('showing-time') || 0;
        if (leaveTime > beginTime) {
            $this.parent().find('ul').hide().data('showing-time', 0);
        }
    }, 100);
});
});
```

Hope this helps.

**update**
Code updated.

I suggest just put the sub menus next to the parent menu item(here, means `li > a` element) to get a better result.

Comment: Good idea, but this solution hide the subitem before mouse can enter into there.

Comment: In `.mouseleave` section need to check where is the mouse... in a child/sibling element or anywhere else? Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would go about it. You don't need javascript at all, at least not for simple hiding/showing. But, if you want to add delays, I would strongly suggest using jquery only to add/remove appropriate css classes with a `settimeout`.

css:

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}

.menu li:hover > .submenu, .submenu.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="...">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 2</a></li>
            <li><ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="...">Sub-subitem 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="...">Subitem 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">Subitem 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="...">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="...">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('body').on('mouseleave','.submenu', function(e) {

    var jTarget = $(e.currentTarget).addClass('show');

    setTimeout(function() {
            jTarget.removeClass('show');
    }, 500);
})
```

Check out this jsfiddle with the js delay:
http://jsfiddle.net/LxL4N/1/