# Which tag is used to create menus, ul or menu?

Tags: html, menu, html-lists

I thank that if i want to create a menu in html, i should use ul tag. But I have just discovered menu tag, so i wanna know, which tag is preferable to create menus. It is

```
<ul>                                          <menu>
<li>LOL</li>                                  <li>LOL</li>
<li>Mmmm</li>                                 <li>Mmmm</li>
</ul>                                         </menu>
```

the same thing?

Comment: you should use the `<nav>` tag by surrounding your `<ul>` if by `menu` you mean a navigation bar.  `<menu>` is for menus of controls, i.e. a menu for a web app or game or something

Comment: So I want to create a navigation bar or something like "Careers 2.0" menu on this site, i should use nav tag, not ul or menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to create a navigation bar (whether is in the top, side, or bottom of your site), the correct semantic mark up would be..

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item One</li>
    <li>Menu Item Two</li>
    <li>Menu Item Three</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Note that you still need a list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`) inside of the `<nav>`.  Semantically, `The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.`

```
<nav>
  <li>Menu Item One</li>
  <li>Menu Item Two</li>
  ...
</nav>
```

WILL NOT WORK.

`<menu>` is for a menu of controls for say a web app or a game or something, not for navigation.  Subtle but important semantic difference.  Also note that `<menu>` does not seem to be supported by any major browsers a the time of this post

Answer (score 0):

This is my go to HTML for a menu.

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
```

This question should clear up a lot of things for you: [<nav> or <menu> (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969801/nav-or-menu-html5)

Comment: W3schools doesn't agree with you : http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_menu.asp. :/

Comment: They're also using code supported by no major browser.

Comment: @BillCriswell Though in this case, their usage of HTML is fine. The `<menu>` element may have been deprecated in HTML4, but it's back for HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element).

Comment: Well, with this new information I'd just use `<ul>` because who the hell knows what will happen with `<menu>`.