# Is there a reason to use <ul> inside of <nav>?

Tags: css, html

I know the new HTML5 `nav` element is for creating navigation menus...obviously...but anytime I see someone using it they tend to put a `ul` inside of it, like so:

```
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=#>Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Item B</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Item C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Is that necessary? Is there an advantage to that? Is there any reason not to just write:

```
     <nav>
        <a href=#>Item A</a>
        <a href=#>Item B</a>
        <a href=#>Item C</a>
     </nav>
```

Or, otherwise, why bother wrapping the `ul` in the `nav`? What's the point? Just to make your markup more "semantic"? Why not just use the `ul` on its own?

Comment: Semantics is basically what it comes down to. `<ul>` declares there are multiple options independent of each other.

Comment: it is just a preference for some. You are right generally unnecessary... but not not required. I use ULs on their own most times and divs instead of the nav

Comment: Voted to close my own question, definitely a duplicate, couldn't find that other one before.

Comment: Good read - http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: The "why" of it is that it adds structure that can be targeted with CSS to alter the appearance of the menu. If you don't need to do that, then the added markup would be superfluous. If you're adding anything to any code because you're "supposed to" rather than because you *need to*, then you're already off track. Write code that accomplishes your goal, not to fulfill a perceived expectation.

Answer (score 7):

It was really a hard time for html5 with a huge discussion about this semantic solution. Main two points of it were:

**Navigation is some kind of unordered list in fact.**

But **navigation can be more complicated also** (headers, `uls` inside `uls`). So the `nav` element cannot induce the `ul` element (as the `<menu>` element does)...

For example:

```
<nav>
    <h3>Main navigation</h3>
    <ul><li>...</li></ul>
    <a href="registernow.php">Register</a>
    <h4>Sub navigation</h4>
    <ul><li>...</li></ul>
</nav>
```

In that case, navigation is much more complicated then simple `ul`.

---

Summing up: **Inside `nav` there can be multiple lists, multiple links, headers, ..., and inter alia single `ul`.**

---

Take a look at a hot discussion about that on css tricks. There are many votes for yes and no to that solution... But after all the solution is now a semantic fact :).

1. NAV vs MENU: [<nav> or <menu> (HTML5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969801/nav-or-menu-html5)
2. Great discussion on css tricks: https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/
3. Wrapup of Navigation in Lists: https://css-tricks.com/wrapup-of-navigation-in-lists/