# Auto-width list of links without use of <ul>

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a list of links for a menu, and I want to explore *not* using `ul` or `ol`, but I find that my approach sizes the `a` elements to be full-width, rather than how `li` children would normally be auto-width.

For example:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```
<nav>
  <a>One</a><!-- these <a> children end up being full-width -->
  <a>Two</a>
  <a>Tree</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why are you "exploring" something that is not semantically correct? I'm just wondering?

Comment: And, btw, you need to also use `nav a { flex: 1 1 0; }` or similar to get them to flex properly. Also, unless you set a specific width, of course they will fill the width of `nav` - that's what flex-elements do.

Comment: Hey junkfoodjunkie, This may ultimately be quite a trivial point, but ordinarily I would nest my `ul` within a `nav` for further semantic clarity, but it would also lead to extra DOM nesting.

This would basically be a way to achieve `menu` before the spec is actually approved. Ideally, I'd have a parent element of `menu` with children of `items`.

Comment: Or just get rid of the `<nav>`-container, use `<ul id="menu">` and have a semantically correct document. Note: a lot of HTML5 is NOT semantically correct, even though they have ammended the specs so it pretends to be ;)

Comment: @Meow  The `<menu>` tag does not replace `<nav>`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4971434/4305494).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start; /* NEW */
}
```

The default setting is `align-items: stretch`, which means flex items will expand the full width of the container.